Tracking booking event using GA4 analytics without GTM
I am trying to create an event on GA4 Analytics account that detects whenever someone clicks the Confirm Booking button and books an appointment, but I am not sure that set the correct matching conditions.
matching conditions on GA4 analytics
Here is the booking function that I am trying to track on the website that was built using GoDaddy.
booking functionality on GoDaddy website
I have tried setting the parameter to value, operator to contains, and then setting value to book, but nothing is happening. Then I tried setting parameter to form_submit_text, setting operator to contains, and setting value to Confirm Booking. But so far nothing is happening.

GA4 interface is somewhat misleading. It allows you to make GA4 events based on other already tracked GA4 events. It does not allow you to track anything new.
Without using GTM or custom scripting (gtag.js) you won't be able to track custom events. GA on it's own is only able to track the most simple things like exit links, downloads, pageviews and scrolls.
You could try a workaround. You could check which page appears after successful booking and look at the instances of that pageview, but it's not very reliable and you'd have to know the data pretty well to do that without severe mistakes in analysis.
